# Is there a way to mutate strings without using all kinds of different methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a project in which i need to split an ID into two separate IDs.
The first Id has a static length of 20 chars and the second is variable.

I currently have the following code in place:

```
mergedUUID = "12345678902345678900123";
const serverUUIDlength = 20;
const cameraId = mergedUUID.slice(serverUUIDlength);
const deviceId = mergedUUID.substring(serverUUIDlength);
```

Resulting in `deviceId` being `12345678902345678900` and `cameraId` `123`.

But this feels "dumb", I use these two different methods while they are doing practically the same, it there a better (more clean) way?

Comment: Strings are immutable. They cannot be mutated. `lenght` might cause confusion for later readers of your code, you might have meant to use `length`

Comment: please add an example of the string and the wanted result. btw, strings are immutable.

Comment: *"it there a better way?"* Use the same method in both places? I don't think I understand the question. It's true that with a single argument that's a positive number, `slice` and `substring` (and `substr`) do the same thing. That doesn't mean you have to mix and match using them. Choose one for that situation and stick with it.

Comment: I have improved the question, my apologies for the initially vague question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing two different methods. While they are really alike there are subtle difference between them.

`substring` has something of a foolproof method to 'always' work. For example it swaps it's parameters around if the given `startIndex` is greater than the `endIndex`. Slice in this case would have returned an empty string.

Example code:

```
var text = 'Mozilla';
console.log(text.substring(5, 2)); // => "zil" 
console.log(text.slice(5, 2));     // => ""
```

To answer your question; you should consider using one method, not both. That's the better way.

For additional documentation, [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#Differences_between_substring()_and_slice()).

Answer (score 1):

You could slice, the one from start, the other one from a given position.

```js
var mergedUUID = "12345678902345678900123",
    serverUUIDlength = 20,
    deviceId = mergedUUID.slice(0, serverUUIDlength),
    cameraId = mergedUUID.substring(serverUUIDlength);

console.log(deviceId);
console.log(cameraId);
```